# Hashcode not hashing properly

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode, string-hashing

I've written a `hashcode` function for this class and for some reason the hashmap is not properly recognizing when a key is actually present in the `HashMap`. (coordinates is a string)

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return coordinates.hashCode();
}
```

And I've also written a `.equals` method for the class that used to test whether two pairs of coordinates were equal to each other; However, to verify that my hashcode method is working correctly I've switched the `.equals` method to the following.

```
public boolean equals(Object arg) {
    Block a = (Block) arg;
    return hashCode() == a.hashCode();
}
```

and they're all being called elsewhere with a `hashmap.containskey()` call as follows:

```
return (hashblocks.containsKey(newz));
```

For some reason this only returns true ~ 50% of the time when it should (we even reinput the exact same case and sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't) I've had a lot of problem in the past trying to get contains methods to work properly for `HashMap`s and `Set`s and I'm wondering why this implementation in particular is having difficulty. (Basically, what could the bug possibly be)

```
3 1 3 1
true
4 2 4 2
false
 0 0 1 0
 0 3 1 3
 2 0 3 0
 2 3 3 3
0 1 1 2
2 1 2 2
4 0 4 0
4 2 4 2
3 1 3 1
3 2 3 2

3 1 3 1
true
4 2 4 2
true
3 2 3 2
true
 0 0 1 0
 0 3 1 3
 2 0 3 0
 3 3 4 3
0 1 1 2
2 1 2 2
4 0 4 0
4 2 4 2
3 1 3 1
3 2 3 2
```

the query is followed by its result and the long set of numbers represents all the keys followed by a newline char

Comment: Please show us a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've just edited the post to include a failed testcase

Comment: That's not how you write an `equals` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to verify that my hashcode method is working correctly I've switched the .equals method to the following.

```
return hashCode()==a.hashCode();
```

This is going to work only in case of "perfect hashing", i.e. when equality of hash codes implies the equality of the actual values. Hash codes of `String` in Java are not perfect (in fact, they cannot be perfect for all possible strings even theoretically).

You need to keep the equality check consistent with hash codes - in your case, that would be checking the equality of `coordinates`:

```
public boolean equals(Object arg) {
    Block a = (Block) arg;
    return coordinates.equals(a.coordinates);
}
```

Comment: what you suggested is the initial setup I had; however, that did not function appropriately. I've even switched the hashcode functions to 'public int hashCode(){
   String[] ints=coordinates.split(" ");
   return Integer.parseInt(ints[0])*1+Integer.parseInt(ints[1])*2+Integer.parseInt(ints[2])*3+Integer.parseInt(ints[3])*4;
  }'
to circumvent this problem of imperfect hashing however I still receive the same error.

Comment: @RaulPuri Is the `coordinates` string changeable, or is it set once in the constructor, and cannot be changed again?

Comment: It is a private variable, but it is intended to be changed as you can move the bloc's coordinates around could this be the problem?

Comment: I encountered a null pointer error occasionally earlier in my code when I tried to move the block around but that fixed itself

Comment: @RaulPuri Basing hash code and equality on mutable fields is dangerous. Here is what could happen: (1) put a block into a hash container, (2) change its coordinates, (3) iterate over the existing blocks from the container. Most blocks whose coordinates have been changed after storing in the container would not be located, because the hash code used to place them is no longer consistent with their new hash code.

Comment: Hmmm that's an interesting problem to have. could I maybe ask you to glance at the testcases that I edited into my file. Even though the key is present in the hashmap the function is not returning the appropriate result. Also I've changed my hashcode function so it parses in all the ints from each line and multiplies each integer by a unique factor to get a final hashcode. I thought this might be able to fix the problem, but clearly I was wrong

Comment: actually you're entirely right the error seems to be in the mutability of the hashcode and I can't seem to comprehend why. My understanding is that it should be basing its hashcode off of whatever the coordinates are

Comment: @RaulPuri When you place a key in a hashmap, the hashmap computes the hash code of the key. Let's say it returns 1. The hashmap places the key in a bucket number 1, after checking other items in that bucket for equality to the new key. Then you change the key, so that its new hash code becomes 7. However, the map does not know about it, so the key remains in bucket 1. When you search the map using another key with hash code 7, hashmap checks bucket number 7, and does not find our object in there, because it remains in the bucket number 1.

Answer (score 2):

Since coordinates seems mutable, you should not use it as `hashCode()`, because you will encounter problem with hash based container, eg:

```
Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
key.setCoordinates("1");
map.put(key, value1); 
key.setCoordinates("2");
map.put(key, value2);
```

The key remains the same, but its `hashCode` is based on `coordinates` which is mutable. In the first case, when `coordinates == "1"`, its value might be 1. Since the Hash map/set use an internal array, of a certain capacity (say 16), it will store the value1 at the following position:

```
map.values[(key.hashCode() % map.values.length)] = value1;
map.values[(1 % 16)] = value1;
map.values[1] = value1;
```

In fact, the array is an array of list (eg: two keys may have the same hash code, and that's where the equals method is used) but I don't want to go down the full implementation of HashMap/Set in Java.

If the `hashCode` mutate, then calling `put` a second times will not work: say that `"2".hashCode()` is 2, and that `key.hashCode()` also returns 2:

```
map.values[(key.hashCode() % map.values.length)] = value2;
map.values[(2 % 16)] = value2;
map.values[2] = value2;
```

But for the same key, you already have a value associated, yet it is not replaced by value2. I can even assume that `System.out.println(map);` will print `[key: value1, key: value2]` in a random order.

That why an `hashCode` method should **avoid** using mutating field, unless you are sure that when you use your map, the keys never mutate.

You should probably return 0, or use the default `hashCode()/equals()`.

The same problem may arise with equals.